# JavaScript Compiler Error in Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to use a cookie to set user pageviews per session through GTM. I'm using a custom JavaScript variable:

```
function readCookie(name) {
    var cookieName = name + "=";
    var cookieSplit = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < cookieSplit.length; i++) {
        var cookies = cookieSplit[i];
        while (cookies.charAt(0) === ' ') cookies = cookies.substring(1, cookies.length);
        if (cookies.indexOf(cookieName) === 0) return cookies.substring(cookieName.length, cookies.length);
    }
    return null; 
}
function viewAppend() {
    var oldCookie = readCookie('viewCount');
    if (oldCookie === null) {
        document.cookie = "viewCount=1; path=/";
    } else {
        var views = oldCookie + 1;
        document.cookie = "viewCount="+views+"; path=/";
    }
}
viewAppend();
```

I keep getting the same Compiler error: "Error at line 12, character 1: Parse error. ')' expected."

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong, but any help is appreciated.

------ EDIT ------
Via my comment below, this is my current code. Current error is : "Error at line 16, character 40: Parse error. Semi-colon expected"

```
function doStuff() {
    function readCookie(name) {
        var cookieName = name + "=";
        var cookieSplit = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i=0;i < cookieSplit.length;i++) {
            var cookies = cookieSplit[i];
            while (cookies.charAt(0) === ' ') cookies = cookies.substring(1,cookies.length);
            if (cookies.indexOf(cookieName) === 0) return cookies.substring(cookieName.length,cookies.length);
        }
        return null;
    }
    function viewAppend() {
        var oldCookie = readCookie('viewCount');
        if (oldCookie === null) {
            document.cookie = "viewCount="1"; path=/";
        } else {
            var views = parseInt(oldCookie) + 1;
            document.cookie = "viewCount="+views+"; path=/";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe GTM doesn't do automatic semicolon insertion? Try adding a `;` at the end of the `var oldCookie` line.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo on my end. The semi colon was there. I think I've narrowed it down to two main issues.

1) I think GTM is going to force me to do wrap everything in a single function.
2) I need to convert oldCookie back into an integer to add 1 before rewriting the cookie.

I'm going to edit the original with my current code.

Comment: 16 is the else statement

Answer (score 2):

You have quoting problems on this line:

```
        document.cookie = "viewCount="1"; path=/";
```

it should be:

```
        document.cookie = "viewCount=1; path=/";
```

You don't need to put quotes around the value of a cookie (and if you did, you could either escape them or use single quotes around the whole string).

Comment: This did it... or got me past the errors. The variable is still showing as undefined on Window Loaded, but I imagine I can fix that by returning the views var?

Comment: That's right, the JS custom variable needs to return a value. `views` should do

Comment: @AndrewRansom What variable is showing as undefined?

Comment: @Barmar I went a different way with it, and it's working fine. I posted my answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I went back to the drawing board and tried approaching the problem another way. At first I was trying to build everything into a single custom JavaScript variable in GTM. That was folly. I decided to approach it as such:

First, I built a custom HTML tag in GTM to read/write the PageView cookie that fired on all pages.

```
<script>
function readCookie(name) {
    var cookieName = name + "=";
    var cookieSplit = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < cookieSplit.length;i++) {
        var cookies = cookieSplit[i];
        while (cookies.charAt(0) === ' ') cookies = cookies.substring(1,cookies.length);
        if (cookies.indexOf(cookieName) === 0) return cookies.substring(cookieName.length,cookies.length);
    }
    return null;
}
function viewAppend() {
    var oldCookie = readCookie('viewCount');
    if (oldCookie === null) {
        document.cookie = "viewCount=1; path=/";
    } else {
        var views = parseInt(oldCookie) + 1;
        document.cookie = "viewCount="+views+"; path=/";          
    }
}
viewAppend();
</script>
```

Then I built a custom Javascript variable that read the cookie and returned it as an integer.

```
function doStuff() {
function readCookie(name) {
    var cookieName = name + "=";
    var cookieSplit = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < cookieSplit.length;i++) {
        var cookies = cookieSplit[i];
        while (cookies.charAt(0) === ' ') cookies = cookies.substring(1,cookies.length);
        if (cookies.indexOf(cookieName) === 0) return cookies.substring(cookieName.length,cookies.length);
    }
    return null;
}
var oldCookie = readCookie('viewCount');
var views = parseInt(oldCookie);
return views;
}
```

Then I simply built my pagievew tag that triggered whenever the pageviews variable was greater than 4 on Window Load to indicate an engaged user.

Thanks @Barmar for the help thinking about the problem. Your questions definitely challenged how I was approaching it.